# Chosing right algorithm between O(n) and O(n^2) when constants are unknown

Tags: java, algorithm

I have given run-time functions for two algorithms solving the same problem. Let's say -

For First algorithm : `T(n) = an + b` (Linear in n)
For second Algorithm: `T(n) = xn^2 + yn + z` (Quadratic in n)

Every book says linear in time is better than quadratic and of course it is for bigger `n` (how big?). I feel definition of Big changes based on the constants `a`, `b`, `x`, `y` and `z`.

Could you please let me know how to find the threshold for `n` when we should switch to algo1 from algo2 and vice-versa (is it found only through experiments?). I would be grateful if someone can explain how it is done in professional software development organizations.

I hope I am able to explain my question if not please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S. - The implementation would be in Java and expected to run on various platforms. I find it extremely hard to estimate the constants `a`, `b`, `x`, `y` and `z` mathematically. How do we solve this dilemma in professional software development?

Comment: The one that minimizes the running time of your *real life usage* would be better - in that particular scenario. In other words, it depends.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, just go with the one with the lowest exponent of n. If you really need to see if you can improve performance by using another algorithm, you need to run experiments for that particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experiment.  I also encountered a situation in which we had code to find a particular instance in a list of instances.  The original code did a simple loop, which worked well for several years.
Once, one of our customers logged a performance problem.  In his case the list contained several thousands of instances and the lookup was really slow.

The solution of my fellow developer was to add hashing to the list, which indeed solved the customer's problem.  However, now other customers started to complain because they suddenly had a performance problem.  It seemed that in most cases, the list only contained a few (around 10) entries, and the hashing was much slower than just looping over the list.

The final solution was to measure the time of both alternatives (looping vs. hashing) and determining the point at which the looping become slower than hashing.  In our case this was about 70.  So we changed the algorithm:

- If the list contains less than 70 items we loop
- If the list contains more then 70 items we hash

The solution will probably be similar in your case.

Comment: Excellent...Exactly that's what I wanted to know...Thanks Patrick

Answer (score 5):

I would always use the O(n) one, for smaller n it might be slower, but n is small anyway. The added complexity in your code will make it harder to debug and maintain if it's trying to choose the optimal algorithm for each dataset.

Comment: And O(n) with O(n^2) + some method for choosing which algorithm to use can be even slower for all cases (because of additional time spent on choosing algo) than just O(n).

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to estimate the fixed factors in all cases of practical interest. Even if you could, it would not help unless you could also predict how the size of the input is going to evolve in the future.

The linear algorithm should always be preferred unless other factors come into play as well (e.g. memory consumption). If the *practical performance* is not acceptable you can then look for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Just profile the code with the expected inputs size, it's even better if you also add in a worst case input. Don't waste your time solving the equation, which might be impossible to derive in the first place.

Generally, you can expect O(n<sup>2</sup>) to be significantly slower than O(n) from size of n = 10000. Significantly slower means that any human can notice it is slower. Depending on the complexity of the algorithm, you might notice the difference at smaller n.

The point is: judging an algorithm based on time complexity allows us to ignore some algorithms that is clearly too slow for any input at the largest input size. However, depending on the domain of the input data, certain algorithm with higher complexity will practically outperform other algorithm with lower time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a maths question, not a programming one.

NB I am going to assume x is positive...

You need to know when

```
an+b < xn^2 + yn + z
```

ie

```
0 < xn^2 + (y-a)n + (z-b)
```

You can plug this into the standard equation for solving quadratics http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula

And take the larger 0, and then you know for all values greater than this (as x positive) O(n^2) is greater.

You end up with a horrible equation involving x, y, a, z, and b that I very much doubt is any use to you.

Comment: Thanks Robert... from above answers I understand since I am not able to estimate precisely a,b,x,y and z (without performing experiments) I would not be able to solve (an+b < xn^2 + yn + z) for a precise n. So either I need to perform experiments for all systems (compilers + computer architecture) it's going to run or need to follow the thumb rule suggested by Jackson...Thanks to all of you guys for prompt response.

Comment: @Ankur Take that rule of thumb with a grain of salt. If the constants (or at least one constant) for the linear algorithm are (is) terrible, it'd be a bad idea. If you can't estimate them abstractly, run with a couple of small inputs to get an estimate of the constants. _Usually_ the constants are of similar magnitude across compilers and architectures. If they are terrible, check the quadratic algorithm. And if you _know_ that the algorithm will never run with large inputs, say you know `n <= 20` always, algorithmic complexity is a red herring anyway.

Comment: "Usually the constants are of similar magnitude across compilers and architectures" - That's really a good point I missed...Thanks Daniel

Answer (score 0):

When we write an algorithm for a large scale purpose, we want it to perform good for large 'n'. In your case, depending upon `a, b, x, y and z`, the second algorithm may perform better though its quadratic. But no matter what the values of `a, b, x, y and z` are, there would be some lower limit of `n` (say `n0`) beyond which first algo (linear one) will always be faster than the second.

```
If f(n) = O(g(n))
then it means for some value of n >= n0 (constant)
f(n) <= c1*g(n)

So
if g(n) = n,
then f(n) = O(n)
```

So choose the algo depending upon you usage of `n`